# Anyone can tell me whats wrong in here when im putting a array of number like :1,2 its starting to freeze the screen i hope someone can help me thanks

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datatables

Hello guys im trying to learn vue and im trying to use datatable from https://datatables.net/ and having a problem with my action button that im not able to get the id when the @viewModal is been triggered i hope someone can help me to get the id of each buttons thanks and here is my code TIA:

**EmployeeDataTable Component :**

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-title">Employee List</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table
          id="employee-table"
          class="table-sm table-bordered table-hover text-center display"
          width="100%"
        >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="pt-3 pb-3">#</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Contact #</th>
              <th>Department</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    //For Datatable to work
    
    import "datatables.net";
    
    import EmployeeEdit from "./EmployeeEdit.vue";
    
    export default {
    
      name: "EmployeeList",
    
      data() {
    
        return {
    
          employees: [],
    
        };
    
      },
    
      mounted() {
    
        this.getEmployeeLists();
    
      },
    
      components: {
    
        "employee-edit": EmployeeEdit,
    
      },
    
      methods: {
    
        getEmployeeLists() {
    
          // INITIALIZE DATATABLE
    
          $("#employee-table")
    
            .DataTable({
    
              //LOADING
    
            //   processing: true,
    
              //AJAX
    
              serverSide: true,
    
              //DIRECTION
    
              order: [[1, "desc"]],
    
              //AJAX
    
              ajax: {
    
                url: "/api/getEmployeeLists",
    
                dataList: "json",
    
                type: "POST",
    
                data: { _token: "{{csrf_token()}}" },
    
              },
    
              //TABLE COLUMNS SHOULD BE THE SAME IN CONTROLLER
    
              columns: [
    
                { data: "#" },
    
                { data: "name" },
    
                { data: "address" },
    
                { data: "contact" },
    
                { data: "department" },
    
                { data: "status" },
    
                {
    
                  data: "actions",
    
                  //allowing modification
    
                  createdCell(cell, cellData, rowData) {
    
                    let EmployeeListDataTableActions = Vue.extend(
    
                      require("./EmployeeListDataTableAction.vue").default
    
                    );
    
                    let instance = new EmployeeListDataTableActions().$mount();
    
                    $(cell).empty().append(instance.$el);
    
                  },
    
                },
    
              ],
    
              //View Count in Table
    
              lengthMenu: [
    
                [10, 25, 50, -1],
    
                [10, 25, 50, "All"],
    
              ],
    
            })
    
            .columns();
    
        },
    
        beforeDestroy: function () {
    
          $(this.$el).DataTable().destroy();
    
        },
    
      },
    
    };
    
</script>
```

**EmployeeDataTableAction Component :**

```
<template>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="viewModal" title="View Employee Details">
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
    </button>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
    
        name: 'EmployeeListDataTableAction',
    
        data: function() {
    
            return {
    
            }
    
        },
    
        mounted() {
    
        },
    
        methods: {
    
            viewModal() {
    
                var id  =   $(this.$el).closest('tr').find('input').val();
    
                return false;
    
                axios
    
                .post(`/api/getEmployeeDetails/${id}`, {
    
                    id: id,
    
                })
    
                .then((response) => {
    
                    $("#edit-employee-modal").modal("show");
    
                    $(".myModalLabel").text(
    
                        response.data.name +
    
                            " - " +
    
                            response.data.department_name
    
                    );
    
                    state.commit("getEmployeeDetailsArray", response.data);
    
                    state.commit("getTransactionId", response.data.id);
    
                })
    
                .catch((response) => {
    
                    this.$toast.top("Something went wrong!");
    
                });
    
           },
    
        },
    
    }
    
</script>
```

**Employee Controller for the DataTable :**

```
public function employeeList(Request $request){
        $all            = Employee::getEmployeeTotal();
        //total count of data
        $total_data     = $all;
        //total filter 
        $total_filtered = $total_data;
        //set_time_limit(seconds)
        $limit          = $request->input('length');
        //start
        $start          = $request->input('start');
        //order
        // $order          = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
        //direction
        $dir           = $request->input('order.0.dir');
        $search_value  = $request->input('search.value');
        if (!empty($search_value)) {
            $posts          = Employee::getEmployeeNameSearch($search_value,$start, $limit, $dir);
            $total_data     = count($posts);
            $total_filtered = $total_data;
        }else{
            if(empty($request->input('search.value')))
            {    
                //if no search
                $posts      = Employee::getEmployeeList($start, $limit, $dir); 
            }
        }
        $data = array();
        if(!empty($posts))
        {
            $counter    = $start + 1;
            foreach ($posts as $post)
            {
                $department                      = GlobalModel::getSingleDataTable('departments',$post->department_id);
                $status                          = StatusController::checkStatus($post->status);
                $nested_data['#']                = '<span style="font-size: 12px ;  text-align: center;">'.$counter++.'</span>';
                $nested_data['name']             = '<p style="text-align: center;">'.$post->name.'</p>';
                $nested_data['address']          = '<p style="text-align: center;">'.$post->address.'</p>';
                $nested_data['contact']          = '<p style="text-align: center;">'.$post->contact.'</p>';
                $nested_data['department']       = '<p style="text-align: center;">'.$department->name.'</p>';
                $nested_data['status']           = '<p style="text-align: center;">'.$status.'</p>';
                $nested_data['actions']           = '';
                $data[]                          = $nested_data;

            }
        }
            $json_data=array(
                                "draw"            => intval($request->input('draw')),  
                                "recordsTotal"    => intval($total_data),  
                                "recordsFiltered" => intval($total_filtered), 
                                "data"            => $data   
                            );
    
            return response()->json($json_data); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second line of your viewModal() function, you are placing a return false; statement. "The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller." From Mozilla docs. That's why the API call is never executing.

Comment: Hello sorry for the late reply i intentionally place return false so the api wont execute i want to know first if theres a data being get with the selection with jquery that i did .